# Java crashed when loading shader

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I am writing GLSL shaders for my application.

However, when the shaders attempt to link, java just crashes.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0facf8f2, pid=92612, tid=93140
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig7icd32.dll+0x3df8f2]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\Downloads\mcp\ship\Ship\hs_err_pid92612.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

I put the error log at `D:\Downloads\mcp\ship\Ship\hs_err_pid92612.log` in a [pastebin here](http://pastebin.com/gZz2gMpy), because I just want to jump to the relevant part:

```
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.nglLinkProgram(IJ)V+0
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glLinkProgram(I)V+15
j      utility.ShaderLoader.loadShaderPair(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I+591
j  Joehot200.TerrainDemo.setUpShaders()V+9
j  Joehot200.TerrainDemo.startGame()V+43
j  StartScreenExperiments.Test2.resartTDemo()V+21
j  StartScreenExperiments.Test2.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+10
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

Which looking at `org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glLinkProgram(I)V+15` shows that the error is OpenGL linking the shaders.

I load shaders with my loadShaderPair which is the following:

```
    public static int loadShaderPair(String vertexShaderLocation, String fragmentShaderLocation, String tesShaderLocation, String tesscontrolShaderLocation) {
    int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    int tesscontrolShader = glCreateShader(GL40.GL_TESS_CONTROL_SHADER);
    int tesShader = glCreateShader(GL40.GL_TESS_EVALUATION_SHADER);
    StringBuilder vertexShaderSource = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder fragmentShaderSource = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder tesShaderSource = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder tesscontrolShaderSource = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader tesShaderFileReader = null;
    try {
        tesShaderFileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tesShaderLocation));
        String line;
        while ((line = tesShaderFileReader.readLine()) != null) {
            tesShaderSource.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    } finally {
        if (tesShaderFileReader != null) {
            try {
                tesShaderFileReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    BufferedReader tesscontrolShaderFileReader = null;
    try {
        tesscontrolShaderFileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tesscontrolShaderLocation));
        String line;
        while ((line = tesscontrolShaderFileReader.readLine()) != null) {
            tesscontrolShaderSource.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    } finally {
        if (tesscontrolShaderFileReader != null) {
            try {
                tesscontrolShaderFileReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    BufferedReader vertexShaderFileReader = null;
    try {
        vertexShaderFileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(vertexShaderLocation));
        String line;
        while ((line = vertexShaderFileReader.readLine()) != null) {
            vertexShaderSource.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    } finally {
        if (vertexShaderFileReader != null) {
            try {
                vertexShaderFileReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    BufferedReader fragmentShaderFileReader = null;
    try {
        fragmentShaderFileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fragmentShaderLocation));
        String line;
        while ((line = fragmentShaderFileReader.readLine()) != null) {
            fragmentShaderSource.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    } finally {
        if (fragmentShaderFileReader != null) {
            try {
                fragmentShaderFileReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    glShaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderSource);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    if (glGetShaderi(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
        System.err.println("Vertex shader wasn't able to be compiled correctly. Error log:");
        System.err.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 1024));
        return -1;
    }
    glShaderSource(tesscontrolShader, tesscontrolShaderSource);
    glCompileShader(tesscontrolShader);
    if (glGetShaderi(tesscontrolShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
        System.err.println("tesscontrol shader wasn't able to be compiled correctly. Error log:");
        System.err.println(GL11.glGetString(GL11.glGetError()));
        System.err.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(tesscontrolShader, 1024));
    }
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderSource);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    if (glGetShaderi(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
        System.err.println("Fragment shader wasn't able to be compiled correctly. Error log:");
        System.err.println(GL11.glGetString(GL11.glGetError()));
        System.err.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 1024));
    }
    glShaderSource(tesShader, tesShaderSource);
    glCompileShader(tesShader);
    if (glGetShaderi(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
        System.err.println("Tessellation shader wasn't able to be compiled correctly. Error log:");
        System.err.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(tesShader, 1024));
        return -1;
    }
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, tesShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, tesscontrolShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    if (glGetProgrami(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
        System.err.println("Shader program wasn't linked correctly.");
        System.err.println(GL11.glGetString(GL11.glGetError()));
        System.err.println(glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 1024));
        System.exit(1);
        return -1;
    }
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    glDeleteShader(tesShader);
    glDeleteShader(tesscontrolShader);
    return shaderProgram;
}
```

Here is my vertex shader:

```
#version 400 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position_VS_in;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 TexCoord_VS_in;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 Normal_VS_in;

uniform mat4 gWorld;

out vec3 WorldPos_CS_in;
out vec2 TexCoord_CS_in;
out vec3 Normal_CS_in;

void main()
{
WorldPos_CS_in = (gWorld * vec4(Position_VS_in, 1.0)).xyz;
TexCoord_CS_in = TexCoord_VS_in;
Normal_CS_in = (gWorld * vec4(Normal_VS_in, 0.0)).xyz;
}
```

Here's my TCS:

```
#version 400 core

// define the number of CPs in the output patch
layout (vertices = 3) out;

uniform vec3 gEyeWorldPos;

// attributes of the input CPs
in vec3 WorldPos_CS_in[];
in vec2 TexCoord_CS_in[];
in vec3 Normal_CS_in[];

// attributes of the output CPs
out vec3 WorldPos_ES_in[];
out vec2 TexCoord_ES_in[];
out vec3 Normal_ES_in[];

float GetTessLevel(float Distance0, float Distance1)
{
float AvgDistance = (Distance0 + Distance1) / 2.0;

if (AvgDistance <= 2.0) {
    return 10.0;
}
else if (AvgDistance <= 5.0) {
    return 7.0;
}
else {
    return 3.0;
}
}

void main()
{
// Set the control points of the output patch
TexCoord_ES_in[gl_InvocationID] = TexCoord_CS_in[gl_InvocationID];
Normal_ES_in[gl_InvocationID] = Normal_CS_in[gl_InvocationID];
WorldPos_ES_in[gl_InvocationID] = WorldPos_CS_in[gl_InvocationID];
// Calculate the distance from the camera to the three control points
float EyeToVertexDistance0 = distance(gEyeWorldPos, WorldPos_ES_in[0]);
float EyeToVertexDistance1 = distance(gEyeWorldPos, WorldPos_ES_in[1]);
float EyeToVertexDistance2 = distance(gEyeWorldPos, WorldPos_ES_in[2]);

// Calculate the tessellation levels
gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = GetTessLevel(EyeToVertexDistance1, EyeToVertexDistance2);
gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = GetTessLevel(EyeToVertexDistance2, EyeToVertexDistance0);
gl_TessLevelOuter[2] = GetTessLevel(EyeToVertexDistance0, EyeToVertexDistance1);
gl_TessLevelInner[0] = gl_TessLevelOuter[2];
}
```

And here's the TES:

```
#version 400 core

layout(triangles, equal_spacing, ccw) in;

uniform mat4 gVP;
uniform sampler2D gDisplacementMap;
uniform float gDispFactor;

in vec3 WorldPos_ES_in[];
in vec2 TexCoord_ES_in[];
in vec3 Normal_ES_in[];

out vec3 WorldPos_FS_in;
out vec2 TexCoord_FS_in;
out vec3 Normal_FS_in;

vec2 interpolate2D(vec2 v0, vec2 v1, vec2 v2)
{
return vec2(gl_TessCoord.x) * v0 + vec2(gl_TessCoord.y) * v1 + vec2(gl_TessCoord.z) * v2;
}

vec3 interpolate3D(vec3 v0, vec3 v1, vec3 v2)
{
return vec3(gl_TessCoord.x) * v0 + vec3(gl_TessCoord.y) * v1 + vec3(gl_TessCoord.z) * v2;
}

void main()
{
// Interpolate the attributes of the output vertex using the barycentric coordinates
TexCoord_FS_in = interpolate2D(TexCoord_ES_in[0], TexCoord_ES_in[1], TexCoord_ES_in[2]);
Normal_FS_in = interpolate3D(Normal_ES_in[0], Normal_ES_in[1], Normal_ES_in[2]);
Normal_FS_in = normalize(Normal_FS_in);
WorldPos_FS_in = interpolate3D(WorldPos_ES_in[0], WorldPos_ES_in[1], WorldPos_ES_in[2]);
// Displace the vertex along the normal
float Displacement = texture(gDisplacementMap, TexCoord_FS_in.xy).x;
WorldPos_FS_in += Normal_FS_in * Displacement * gDispFactor;
gl_Position = gVP * vec4(WorldPos_FS_in, 1.0);
}
```

Not sure if it is relevant or not, but when I change `#version 400 core` to `#version 410 core` in the vertex shader, I get the following error:

```
Vertex shader wasn't able to be compiled correctly. Error log:
ERROR: 0:? : '' :  Incorrect GLSL version: 410
WARNING: -1:65535: 'GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location' :  extension is not available in current GLSL   version
WARNING: -1:65535: 'GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location' :  extension is not available in current GLSL version
WARNING: 0:3: extension GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location is being used but no proper #version pragrma was used
WARNING: -1:65535: 'GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location' :  extension is not available in current GLSL version
WARNING: -1:65535: 'GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location' :  extension is not available in current GLSL version
WARNING: 0:4: extension GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location is being used but no proper #version pragrma was used
WARNING: -1:65535: 'GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location' :  extension is not available in current GLSL version
WARNING: -1:65535: 'GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location' :  extension is not available in current GLSL version
WARNING: 0:5: extension GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location is being used but no proper #version pragrma was used
```

I just can't work out what I am doing wrong with this code. Because java is crashing, I am not getting any other information apart from the line of code it happens on, which is making it really hard to debug.

So, how can I get these shaders to load correctly without crashing or "extension is not available in current GLSL version" or whatever else might go wrong?

I have been led to believe it is something to do with my driver only supporting OpenGL 4.0.. So is it possible to somehow modify the code to use only OpenGL 4.0 methods, or some way of using the above-4.0 methods?
And does this mean that computers with sub-4.0 OpenGL would have an issue? What if a person's driver only supported OpenGL 3.2? Could I fix it for them too?

(Basically I just would like the shaders to work on my computer without changing their functionality significantly)

Comment: Your driver does not appear to support GLSL 4.10 from the warnings you have listed. That's not really all that relevant. But one thing that really confuses me is this: `int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL40.GL_TESS_CONTROL_SHADER)`. Your code listing shows a VS, TES and TCS but no fragment shader... moreover, the thing you call a `fragmentShader` is actually being compiled as if it were a TCS. When it comes time to link this program, you have a VS, TCS and TES as far as GL is concerned and no FS -- which is probably the reason linking bugs out.

Comment: nah the warnings are about `GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location` only being core in glsl 4.2.0 and up (which is why I like to call it "420 layout")

Comment: @PeterT: Excuse me, I meant to say the error: "Incorrect GLSL version: 410". Misread that as a warning.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I added a fragment shader and corrected the names. But it is still crashing for some reason. Updated OP with the code.

Comment: @PeterT Is there any alternatives to 'GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location' which I can put in my shader?

Comment: @Joehot200 I don't think that's you issue, if you remove the `core` it'll probably lose the warning too. Your GPU seems to have the extension, it's just not part of `410 core` so that's why you get a warning. My comment will not help you, I was just saying that the warnings are unrelated to your problem, so that you aren't chasing down the wrong path

Comment: @PeterT Thanks! I removed the '#version' bit, but now I am getting '"Attribute Position_VS_in is bound to generic attribute 0, but gl_Vertex is also used."'. How do I fix that? And also, please tell me if I should make another question for this (even though it is a similar issue).

Comment: @Joehot200 I didn't mean you should remove it completely, I mean you should try `#version 410` instead of `#version 410 core`, if for some reason you don't want to require `420`. Anyway the code you posted doesn't use `gl_Vertex` anywhere, so I can't help you. Again, I'm not talking about the Error, I was just talking about the warnings

Comment: @Joehot200 anyway, the relevant thing I have to say about the crash is that the crash is in the Intel OpenGL implmentation "ig7icd32.dll". So this is a driver issue, try to update your drivers if you can.